# Correct Normal Map format to use for SceneKit content - DirectX or OpenGL?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, directx, scenekit, normals

I wonder, which format for Normal Maps is the correct one to use within SceneKit content, for iOS? As referenced here: [DirectX vs. OpenGL normal maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf9jo.png).

OpenGL or DirectX? Or does is not matter?

Comment: "*As referenced here: DirectX vs. OpenGL normal maps.*" Where does that image come from, and what is it referring to? OpenGL and D3D do not define a "normal map format".

Comment: Sometimes, when iEx purchasing a model, there are two versions of Normal Maps within the downloads (DX, and GL). When using the physically based lighting model in SceneKit, which one would be the map to use? - The image comes from here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100017/directx-vs-opengl-normal-maps

Comment: If you're using someone else's shaders, then you should use the "format" of normal maps that they say. Look at their docs and see what coordinate system they expect the normals in the map to be in.

Comment: Generally you can invert them by just flipping the Green/Y channel value.

Comment: I already did this in Photoshop - but then I still don't exactly know which one is the correct map to have. Looking at the referenced image (from my question) and assuming I have a plane put on scene, on which I'd like to have an imaginary, but visible bump in the middle. Which normal map would give me accurate rendering results. The OpenGL or the DirectX version? Using SceneKit, on iOS Device, with the physically based lighting model enabled, (which will use Metal in the endeffect).

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure it out by testing the OpenGL vs. DirectX Normal Map Typus side by side on planes. This gives me the following results:

[image: OpenGL vs. DirectX Normal Map Type in SceneKit]

This means, if you have the choice between the OpenGL or the DirectX Normal Map, you better choose OpenGL.